# Google colab notebooks not opening

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I try to open a colab notebook it's stuck on the Loading screen. When I go to console it shows the error as seen in the image. I would appreciate if someone could help me resolve this.
[image]

Comment: It would be better to post the error as text and not as image, it is more readable. Have you tried on a different browser?

Comment: I have tried different browsers, systems, and even using a VPN

Comment: I see that a lot of people is opnening posts here on SO that Colab is not working. Maybe it's a Google issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. There was probably an error on Google's end. Thanks for all your help.